# Homebrew on Monterey running opencore

Tags: xcode, homebrew, monterey, mac-pro

I have an old Mac 5,1 running Monterey via OpenCore and can't use homebrew.

1. I do not have read/write permissions on `/usr/local/` or any subdirectories and no ability to `chown` anything there. I have already tried to `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` and the result is `Operation not permitted` on all files and directories.
2. I can't seem to disable `SIP`. Booting to recovery and running `csrutil disable` does not disable `SIP`.
3. I edited OpenCore `config.plist` to remove `SIP` there. No effect.

I can't uninstall homebrew, I can't reinstall or update homebrew, and I can't install any new packages.

This all happened with the Monterey update.

Is there any way to fix homebrew on this machine?

Comment: @mmmmmm - what makes you think the OP doesn't have a Mac? They open with 'old Mac 5,1' which is most likely to be a late 'cheesegrater' Mac Pro. I think part of the issue is that you're not supposed to be able to edit anything in /usr on Monterey, nor will disabling SIP help, because of the protected boot volume. I think we're looking in the wrong direction - where does Homebrew install to since Big Sur?? [idk I never tried]

Comment: What does ls -ls /usr/local show ?

Comment: lilbiscuit - I'm afraid i know nothing about homebrew itself. I just know you cannot get user access to the protected system drive any more; this is why your 1, 2 & 3 fail. You should concentrate on why the [un]install failed [which is way outside my knowledge, sorry], not why you can't access/mod those folders after the fact.

Comment: The initial install of Homebrew will ask you for your password.  The installer will change the permissions on `/usr/local` once it has an admin credential.  If you are not an admin of the machine, you will not be able to install Homebrew.  SIP is not involved, `/usr/local` is not protected by SIP.

Comment: `ls -ls /usr/local` indicates  `drwxrwxr-x    lilbiscuit:admin` for `Homebrew` directory and others as well.

Comment: @MarcWilson Homebrew was installed several OSX versions ago.

Comment: Can you please focus on the homebrew issue, and add some details about permissions and what happens if you run `brew doctor` or `brew update`?

Comment: @nohillside Running either command results in `The following directories are not writable by your user` followed by all the directories Homebrew needs to access.

Comment: Please edit the question (just copy/paste the command and the output), don‘t hide it in the comments :-) And then run `sudo chown -R …` on the directories.

Comment: @nohillside the question already noted this...no ability to chown anything. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Please copy/paste directly from Terminal, don't just describe what you do. Details often matter and can easily be lost by paraphrasing. In the specific case: what does `brew --prefix` return?

Comment: @nohillside `Mac-Pro-2:local david$ brew --prefix
/usr/local`

Comment: Solved. `/usr/local/` is protected by `SIP` and I was finally able to disable `SIP` and work with Homebrew. I will reenable `SIP`.

Comment: The question is now open again, so you can post your solution as an answer (in case somebody else with the same problem finds this page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to disable SIP and restore permissions and Homebrew functionality [through OpenCore](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/troubleshooting/extended/post-issues.html#disabling-sip).